# R one-dimensional optimization and confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, optimization

Is it possible to estimate confidence intervals for single parameter using R `optim()`?. For example, below R code is to estimate $\lambda$ of Poisson distribution. I want to know how to estimate confidence intervals for estimated parameter $\lambda$. Appreciate if anyone can help.

```
loglik.poisson <- function(x, lambda){ 
                     -sum(x * log(lambda) - log(factorial(x)) - lambda) 
                     }

optim(par = 2, loglik.poisson, x = x)
```

Comment: Confidence intervals with normality assumptions, bootstrap confidence intervals (e.g. percentile or bca-intervals),...? More information would be helpful.

Comment: YukiJ, Thanks for response, CI with normality assumptions is the one I need

Comment: @Lank Bootstrap is simple and very common.

Comment: @SmallChess Thanks for your prompt reply. Bootstrapping works fine when x is data vector. How do you bootstrap when x is a matrix?. The entries in rows (columns) are not uniformly distributed. and, if bootstrap apply for the matrix , it should preserve the original row entries (column entries) distribution.

Comment: If the function `f` is the likelihood (as in the Poisson example), then you can calculate a likelihood-based confidence interval. See [How to create an interval estimate based on being within some percentage of the maximum value of the likelihood function?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/467175/237901).